# How to pack latest changes using npm pack?

Tags: npm, npm-publish, npm-pack

I am trying to test one of the package locally. What I do is go the root directory of my package and run

```
npm pack
```

It creates .tgz file and I install this file via `npm i <path to file>`. Now I found that some of my recent changes are missing in this .tgz file. I have made some tiny modifications in css file and those are not reflected in packaged .tgz file. I am not sure what is wrong here. I have looked into internet but all questions in SA and other resources says to use 'npm pack' to create tgz file, but not about this issue.

npm version 6.14.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you do `npm run build` to build the latest code change? I encountered the same issue today and this was the step I forgot.

To troubleshoot, you can unzip the tgz and inspect the source files there directly to see if they are the latest version.

You can also look into the `dist` folder in your local repository. After running `npm run build`, the source code in `dist` folder should reflect the latest code.

Comment: This helped, https://www.robinwieruch.de/publish-npm-package-node/

Comment: I had to install babel,as mentioned in above url, then use it like "babel src -d lib && tsc". This generated lib directory and after that I created tgz using npm pack

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the old tgz file then again run npm run pack. It will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not a case of missing a build step. I didn't have a build script in my local package. It also doesn't answer why my initial code worked but my subsequent changes were not getting picked up by the `npm pack` command.

It turned out it was an npm caching issue. Even deleting the .tgz file did not help, nor did deleting the package dir in the node_modules dir itself.
The main cause was npm's cache needing a call to cache clean: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-cache

So clearing the cache (specifically `npm cache clean <key>`) solved it.
To figure out the cache key, run `npm cache ls` and look for/grep the key based on the name of your package.

Another alternative is to update the version property in your local package's package.json, then updating the reference to the tgz file in your project's package.json dependencies, this will generate a new tgz file, therefore creating a new cache entry (however, not so practical a solution during development).